# Freeform form not showing

Tags: templates, solspace-freeform, solspace

Really odd problem.

Upgraded an EE site to latest version (2.9 from 2.5.2) with Freeform upgraded from 3.14 to 4.2.0. I've migrated all the relevant data using Freeform's built-in utility and updated the relevant parameters but the form is not showing in the template.

Even if I create a new template with the following code nothing is returned to the screen:

```
{exp:freeform:form}
    THIS IS A FORM
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Any thoughts on how to debug or resolve?

Cheers

Cole

Comment: passing the form name or form id as a parameter?

Comment: Do you get output of anything OUTSIDE the tag pair?

Comment: Passing form name or id doesn't affect. And everything outside the tag pair is returned as expected.

Comment: what does template debugging tell you?

Comment: It's getting to the tags but says it is Returning No Results Content: https://gist.github.com/cole007/131266d93b941f6e92d8

Answer (score 2):

Got to the bottom of this, thanks.

The templates had a form_id attribute to create the html id attribute of the form.
This should of course have been the numeric id of the form it was referencing.

Thanks all for responding!

Cheers

Cole

https://gist.github.com/cole007/fe14b74f8e760d180c61